# How do you set Command Timeout in Linqpad?

Tags: timeout, linqpad, command-timeout

I have recently started using LinqPad, and bought the Autocomplete option and am really loving it.  This is an excellent product!

I wanted to ask if there is a way for me to control the command timeout that used when querying a SQL Server database in LinqPAD (I am using c# statements)?  I can't see where we have access to the actual connection string, and I have some large queries for reporting that are timing out. It appears that the timeout is hard-coded at 30 seconds.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have run queries that have taken minutes and never had a command time out. That said, here's how you change it...

---

All of the work you perform inside a `UserQuery`. The `CommandTimeout` is a property of that.

```
this.CommandTimeout = 60;
```

Have a look at all the properties under `this`. It gives you a nice insight into some of the things you can do.

Comment: THANK YOU! (Especially for the near-immediate response!  (kicking myself for not having checked out 'this'!)  (given that I do it a million times a day on my own code!)  Anyway, it worked perfectly!

Comment: It's a nice feature, I not sure why it isn't documented better.

Comment: @user1090088 - Would you mind accepting the answer in keeping with the SO style: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask ? Thanks.

Comment: By default, LINQPad sets the command timeout to infinite. If you're getting timeout errors, I would suspect it's either the connection (rather than the command) that's timing out, or the timeout is to do with the network or server.

Comment: @Joe Albahari, I do get time-outs when/if [LinqPad connects to DB using an EF-library](http://www.linqpad.net/entityframework.aspx). Is there a way to set a/the default time-out to infinite for EF-libraries.  ([My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15543838/422877) already shows an ad hoc way for the command window.)

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned in [@DaveShaw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8448882/422877) when querying a SQL Server database in LinqPAD using a 'regular' connection, you can use:

```
this.CommandTimeout = 60
```

However, this property is not available when [LinqPad connects to DB using an EF-library](http://www.linqpad.net/entityframework.aspx). 
Using `this.CommandTimeout` results in:

> 'UserQuery' does not contain a definition for 'CommandTimeout' and no extension method 'CommandTimeout' accepting a first argument of type 'UserQuery' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

Some puzzling and a this answer [about EF time-outs in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12944012/422877) led me to use this on an EF-connection:

```
(this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 60;
```

Answer (score 5):

For Entity Framework Core connections used the following property instead.
`this.Database.SetCommandTimeout(120);`