# Why does Entity Framework over SQL Express ignore timeout?

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-express, connection-timeout

I have following connection string:

metadata=res://*/Database.csdl|res://*/Database.ssdl|res://*/Database.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='Database.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Connection Timeout=300;"

I expect that this connection string can never get timeout (because it is 5 mins). However, on a very easy database.table.Count() call to Entity Framework it fails in 10 seconds with "Timeout" exception.
Why does Entity Framework ignores SQL timeout? How to set timeout for Entity Framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Timeouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232633/entity-framework-timeouts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connection timeout specifies the amount of time to spend waiting for a connection. It doesn't affect the amount of time that a *query* can spend before timing out.

For that, you need to search for a [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.commandtimeout.aspx) property on whatever database context class you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Connection Timeout is the amount of time to wait whilst attempting to connect to the DB server not executing a query