# Set database timeout in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-timeout

My command keeps timing out, so I need to change the default command timeout value.

I've found `myDb.Database.Connection.ConnectionTimeout`, but it's `readonly`.

**How can I set the command timeout in *Entity Framework 5* ?**

Comment: FYI, On EF6, `Database.CommandTimeout` is no longer read-only

Comment: @itsho He was talking about `Database.Connection.ConnectionTimeout`. Anyway, I would say that `Database.CommandTimeout` is the right thing in the case your query is time-outing (exception `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException` containing `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Timeouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232633/entity-framework-timeouts)

Comment: I assume you actually don't care about the CONNECTION timeout, but instead you want to adjust the COMMAND timeout.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Try this on your context:

```
public class MyDatabase : DbContext
{
    public MyDatabase ()
        : base(ContextHelper.CreateConnection("Connection string"), true)
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180; // seconds
    }
}
```

---

If you want to define the timeout in the connection string, use the `Connection Timeout` parameter like in the following connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>

<add name="AdventureWorksEntities"
connectionString="metadata=.\AdventureWorks.csdl|.\AdventureWorks.ssdl|.\AdventureWorks.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=localhost;
Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60;
multipleactiveresultsets=true'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

</connectionStrings>
```

Source: [How to: Define the Connection String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896291.aspx)

Comment: I would recommend using the connection string version as if you try to access the `ObjectContext` in this constructor sometimes the [PowerShell/NuGet console commands will fail in a circular way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169281/receiving-the-model-backing-the-context-context-has-changed-on-add-migrati).

Comment: Connection Timeout and CommandTimeout and two separate things.  The connection string setting, Connection Timeout, won't affect the amount of time the command runs (CommandTimeout).

Comment: Might be because this is an answer is a year old but `Connection Timeout` raises an `EntityException` "The underlying provider failed on Open". The actual valid value is `Connect Timeout` but it appears to be ignored by EF anyway.

Comment: My problem was a litte different. I got timeout during migrations. EF has a similar property to set for using during migrations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration.commandtimeout

Comment: Depending on what version of EF you use, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6234593/2874896) to get a feeling about the different API's in how to specify the CommandTimeout property.

Comment: Does not work for me (Connection vs Command not being teh same thing I suspect). This post solved it though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232633/entity-framework-timeouts

Comment: My Connection Timeout was set OK but discovered `CommandTimeout` was null. I set `CommandTimeout` as per @leniel-macaferi 's suggestion and it solved my timeout issue. -So they are not the same thing and both need to be set to enable a custom timeout to be set in EF.

Comment: @Karsten - thanks for the tip about dbmigrationsconfiguration! I would have tinkered with the context command timeout until the cows come home.

Comment: The connection string solution leads to "Keyword not supported: 'connection timeout'."

Comment: Yes these are 2 different things command timeout and connection timeout. command timeout is what you want not connection timeout

Answer (score 201):

You can use `DbContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 180; // seconds`

It's pretty simple and no cast required.

Comment: Very useful for us that use `Fluent API` form of EF.

Answer (score 21):

My partial context looks like:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext (string ConnectionString)
        : base(ConnectionString)
    {
        this.SetCommandTimeOut(300);
    }

    public void SetCommandTimeOut(int Timeout)
    {
        var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        objectContext.CommandTimeout = Timeout;
    }
}
```

I left `SetCommandTimeOut` public so only the routines I need to take a long time (more than 5 minutes) I modify instead of a global timeout.

Answer (score 10):

In the generated constructor code it should call `OnContextCreated()`

I added this partial class to solve the problem:

```
partial class MyContext: ObjectContext
{
    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
        this.CommandTimeout = 300;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I extended Ronnie's answer with a fluent implementation so you can use it like so:

`dm.Context.SetCommandTimeout(120).Database.SqlQuery...`

```
public static class EF
{
    public static DbContext SetCommandTimeout(this DbContext db, TimeSpan? timeout)
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = timeout.HasValue ? (int?) timeout.Value.TotalSeconds : null;

        return db;
    }

    public static DbContext SetCommandTimeout(this DbContext db, int seconds)
    {
        return db.SetCommandTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For Database first Aproach:

We can still set it in a constructor, by override the **ContextName.Context.tt** T4 Template this way:

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
{
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base("name=<#=container.Name#>")
    {
        Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
#>
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
<#
}
```

`Database.CommandTimeout = 180;` is the acutaly change.

The generated output is this:

```
public ContextName() : base("name=ContextName")
{
    Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
}
```

If you change your Database Model, this template stays, but the actualy class will be updated.

Comment: Is there way we can specify timeout in Template using some config file.?

Comment: not sure, if there something build in (I wasn't able to find something). But instead of hardcoding 180, you can use [`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyname"]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189364/reading-settings-from-app-config-or-web-config-in-net) @shas

Answer (score 8):

Same as other answers, but as an extension method:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void SetCommandTimeout(this IObjectContextAdapter db, TimeSpan? timeout)
    {
        db.ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = timeout.HasValue ? (int?) timeout.Value.TotalSeconds : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: and how do i call this extension method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple
:
`dbContext.Database.SetCommandTimeout(300);`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran in to this problem and resolved it by updating my application configuration file. For the connection in question, specify "Connection Timeout=60" (I am using entity framework version 5.0.0.0)

[ConnectionTimeout Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khk1C.png)

Comment: connection timeout != command timeout!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Connection string property is readonly. Also, the entities constructor is autogenerated so I didn't want to put it in there. Plus, putting in the constructor applied to all and I only needed it on one sproc.

Below is my workaround

```
try
     { using (MyEntities Mydb = new MyEntities())
       {
         (Mydb as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 600;
         Mydb.LongRunningSproc();
        }
      }
  catch (System.Data.Common.DbException ex)
      {
          throw new Exception(SomeMessageHere);
      }
```

Answer (score -2):

You should make the changes in the Connection String tag in the web config and make the EntityFrameWork read from it in its contructor.

1. Add this term to the web.config Connection String:
   Connection Timeout=300;
2. Add the following code in the constructor:

   Database.CommandTimeout = Database.Connection.ConnectionTimeout;

By this approach you will make the user able to control the time out without make a new publish for him.

Comment: As noted earlier: connection timeout != command timeout. Command timeout is what matters here.

Comment: This approach was to read it dynamically from the Connection String rather than making a separate setting for it.

Comment: That detail escaped my eye, and that immediately shows the problem with such hacks. It's totally unexpected and should never be done.

Comment: The hacking checks should be done from other places and I thing the command time out of the command should be long enough to execute long queries or SQL commands. So the admin of the website should be able to control this period according to his needs without getting a new publish for just changing the command time out period.

Comment: NOT by abusing the *Connection Timeout* setting in the connection string! The next application manager will set it to some other value, unaware of its implications. And, remember, it *also* sets the connection timeout (obviously). You don't want people to wait for 5 minutes if the connection happens to be unavailable due to some contingency.