# Issue while adding and updating new colums in a table with huge data

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework 5 to Microsoft azure server. **I have a table with millions of records in it.** I need to add two columns and update them to given values. I wrote the code as follows:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.MST_FarmerProfile", "Season", c => c.String(maxLength: 500));
    AddColumn("dbo.MST_FarmerProfile", "Year", c => c.Int());

    Sql("Update MST_FarmerProfile Set Season='Kharif' where Season is NULL");
    Sql("Update MST_FarmerProfile Set Year=2013 where Year is NULL");
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropColumn("dbo.MST_FarmerProfile", "Year");
    DropColumn("dbo.MST_FarmerProfile", "Season");

}
```

After deploying it in Azure server, I'm constantly getting '**The wait operation timed out**' exception and nothing is working.

Comment: You can remove the "where" which prevents an expensive index scan. But I think you should define the new columns as `not null` with default value. Make columns `not null` whenever possible.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the time out value ?
Try this if not : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788972/set-database-timeout-in-entity-framework