# C# EF ASP.NET Web API timeout - how can I call a long running query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# code that I want to execute.

```
  str = "SELECT u.LastName " +
                      ",COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT pc.PhraseId), 0) AS CreatedByQty " +
                      ", COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT pm.PhraseId), 0) AS ModifiedByQty " +
                      "FROM dbo.AspNetUsers u " +
                      "LEFT JOIN dbo.Phrase pc " +
                      "ON u.Id = pc.CreatedBy " +
                      "LEFT JOIN dbo.Phrase pm " +
                      "ON u.Id = pm.ModifiedBy " +
                      "GROUP BY u.LastName ";
                threeColQuery = db.Database.SqlQuery<threeCol>(str);
                threeColReport = await threeColQuery.ToListAsync();
                return Ok(threeColReport);
```

I know from running the query in SQL Server manager that it takes about 30 seconds.

When running in a Web API Call I get this:

```
"innerException":{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"The wait operation timed
```

Is there a way I can allow a WebAPI call to run a long running query?

Comment: You can set this programmatically in the controller like this:-

`HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;`

Comment: You can change the timeout of your `DbContext` like this `db.Database.CommandTimeout = 60;`. Would you mind posting the code of your api?

Comment: Actually I forgot to ask whether the timeout is in your client when waiting the api, or inside your api when executing the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the timeout settings on Entity Framework should do the trick.

```
db.Database.CommandTimeout = 60;
```

I would also advise against setting a global default timeout via the connection string. A minute is way too high for most queries, your 30-second query is an exception to the rule (thus you're knowingly increasing the timeout period).

By preventing all timeout exceptions across your app you lose a good indicator of another query misbehaving - leading to long term performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the connection timeout with Sql.

Two approach to do that

1. Increase the connection timeout for this query like

`db.Database.CommandTimeout = 60`

2. Set the timeout property globally. For that follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12789015)