# how to set query timeout for an entitydatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, entitydatasource

I have a C# webform that uses a gridview bound to an **EntityDataSource**.
Now when I run an extensive query I get a timeout on the underlying sql query.

*Anyone knows how to set the query timeout using EntityDataSource?*

I found a few articles that state how to do that with a SqlDataSource but not with EntityDataSource.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the timeout using the connectionstring.

From msdn [How to: Define the Connection String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896291.aspx)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdventureWorksEntities"
    connectionString="metadata=.\AdventureWorks.csdl|.\AdventureWorks.ssdl|.\AdventureWorks.msl;
    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=localhost;
    Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60;
    multipleactiveresultsets=true'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Note the relevant part:

```
Connection Timeout=60;
```

**Edit:**

I just read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232633/entity-framework-timeouts) there is a known bug when you set the TimeOut in the Entity Framework ConnectionString. So you might want to set the TimeOut directly on the context as noted in the answer.

```
this.context.CommandTimeout = 60;
```

Or:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this.context).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 60;
```