# Code first custom SQL migration timeout exception

Tags: sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, full-text-indexing

I am trying to create FULL TEXT index using Entity Framework Migration by executing custom Sql.

My migration class looks like this:

```
public partial class DocumentContentFullTextIndex : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Attachments", "ContentType", c => c.String(maxLength: 260));

        Sql("CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FullTextIndexes AS DEFAULT;", true);

        Sql(@"CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [Attachments](
Content
    TYPE COLUMN ContentType
    Language 'ENGLISH'
)
KEY INDEX [PK_dbo.Attachments]
ON FullTextIndexes;", true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Attachments", "ContentType", c => c.String(maxLength: null));

        Sql("DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON [Attachments]");
        Sql("DROP FULLTEXT CATALOG FullTextIndexes");
    }
}
```

When I run it from MSSQL management studio everything is perfect and SQL did exactly what I am expected from it.

But when running from migration project second Sql request fires exception

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Full stack trace with -Verbose flag:

```
Update-Database -ConnectionStringName DatabaseContext -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'Lx2'.
Using NuGet project 'Database.Model'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'Lx2' (DataSource: ., Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Explicit).
Applying explicit migrations: [201406050348083_AttachmentsContentFullTextIndex].
Applying explicit migration: 201406050348083_AttachmentsContentFullTextIndex.
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Attachments] ALTER COLUMN [ContentType] [nvarchar](260) NULL
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FullTextIndexes AS DEFAULT;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [Attachments](
Content
    TYPE COLUMN ContentType
    Language 'ENGLISH'
)
KEY INDEX [PK_dbo.Attachments]
ON FullTextIndexes;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
ClientConnectionId:3d298f0a-e2dc-4976-8587-c69d03b23c6b
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

I tried to copy all SQL from Verbose output exactly 'as is' and execute it directly in Management Studio and it work exactly as expected with no errors.

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Strange thing also that if I put ContentType max length changing code

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Attachments", "ContentType", c => c.String(maxLength: 260));
```

in separate migration file everything also works fine.

### UPDATE:

After [shivakumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2248845/shivakumar) advice I tried to increase connection timeout (up to 5 minutes) in migration configuration and this increased time before I received "Timeout exception" but problem is still there.

Answer (score 62):

Use Configuration.cs file to set custom time out:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ContextKey = "YourDbContext";

        // New timeout in seconds
        this.CommandTimeout = 60 * 5; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This saved me! The other configurations (connection-string or Setting in on the context.Database.CommandTimeout) did not work for migration in EF6.

Comment: if I run update-database from Package Manager Console then it fails after 5 minutes even if I set a bigger timeout. but if I run from a program (console application) then it works fine.

Comment: How does this constructor get called? What namespace should it be placed in?

Comment: If you are already using EF6 migrations, this confguration file will already exist within your migrations folder. The key point of this answer is to add the timeout within the constructor, the class will already exist.

Comment: @Extragorey just do a project/solution wide search for `DbMigrationsConfiguration` and you should be able to locate this file.

Answer (score 3):

Your request processing may be taking more time than default command timeout of entity framework(30 sec).
You can increase command timeout if necessary as in thread below.

[Entity Framework Timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232633/entity-framework-timeouts)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to set up timeout to 5 minutes and this increased time until I got “timeout exception” to 5 minutes so I think I did that correctly but exception is still there :(