# SQL Timeout when running an Entity Framework Migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am currently experiencing a SQL Timeout when running a SQL() command inside of an EF Migration.

Situation:
I am replacing a bunch (>50) tables with one table, and need to convert the data from those tables I'm about to drop into the new table. I've organized the Migration the following way:

1.Create the new table.

2. In the same Migration, use the SQL() function to run a sql script that migrates the data.

3.Drop all the old tables.

Currently, the migration gives the following error:

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out`

The error is happening in an environment where I give them an installer, and they run it without me involved, so I can't manually run individual migrations, and pause in the middle to run the SQL script.

Is there any way to change the timeout for a connection, or get around this issue?

Environment:

EF 6.0 Code First

SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 8):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26074522/4625305).

> Use Configuration.cs file to set custom time out:
>
> internal sealed class Configuration :
>
> ```
> DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
> {
>     public Configuration()
>     {
>         AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
>         ContextKey = "YourDbContext";
>
>         // New timeout in seconds
>         this.CommandTimeout = 60 * 5; 
>     }
> }
> ```

With this method, you can change the timeout only for migration and not everyone using your default connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the connection timeout in the connection string, something like:

```
Connection Timeout=180;
```

Comment: Can't we just change the timeout just for the migration? Changing it in the connection string will change it for users of the app as well and I don't want that.

Comment: Found out that you can mannually overwrite the connection string when using "Package Manager Console", but didn't how it could be used for automatic migration.

Comment: -1 as this is the "Connection Timeout", whereas the timeout in the question is a "Command Timeout" which isn't part of the connection string