# Entity Framework - Timeout expired error on AlterColumn migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, azure

I have relatively large table with 7,517,717 records in my Azure SQL DB (which is on Azure V12 server, and it is on P4 pricing tier).

When I created table I forgot to define the `MaxLength` for a property, so now it is of type `nvarchar(max)`.

I wanted to change this so I created migration (using FluentAPI) which looks like this:

```
 public partial class FeedTitleMaxLength : DbMigration
 {
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Feed", "Title", c => c.String(maxLength: 100));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Feed", "Title", c => c.String());
    }
 }
```

I've run `Update-Database` command like this:

```
Update-Database -Verbose -ConnectionString "Data Source=serverUrl,1433;Database=dbName;User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=3000;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

My connection string in `web.config` looks the same. And I've also defined timeout like this:

```
 this.Database.CommandTimeout = 3000;
```

But no matter what I do or try I get this error after 30/40 seconds:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. This failure occurred while attempting to connect to the routing destination. The duration spent while attempting to connect to the original server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=97; handshake=110; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=0; [Post-Login] complete=32;

Is there any way I can run this migration? Or some workaround? Can I, for example, create migration but run the `AlterColumn` command in SQL and then `Update-Database` command. Would this mess things or not?

Comment: Connection timeout doesn't help. You should set the *command timeout*, but that's not a connection string setting. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24051417/861716) works for you.

Comment: @GertArnold this helped, thanks a lot :)