# The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation from iis ftp-site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-8, nopcommerce, sql-server-2014

I have deployed `nopcommerce v3.40` website at IIS with binding FTP site. But I failed to install plugin & it gives an error

> "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding."

This plugin creates table with data on sqlserver by sqlscript.

Moreover, When I execute same script which execute thru plugin directly at database on sqlserver it creates table with data successfully without any error.

Also connection String is:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Nop24_34;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Connect Timeout=30000
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mentioned above problem is resolved. It is due to

> **ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 600;**

is not set in my code.

Also refer this link: [Entity Framework Timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232633/entity-framework-timeouts)

Hope this will helpful to someone.