# Set Command Timeout in EF 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, command-timeout

I want to set command timeout for query execution, currently I am doing `context.Database.CommandTimeout = 90;` but i feel this is not working,
I tried checking the process logs in database but found the time difference was always less than 90sec.

Can someone help how can I set the database timeout in Entity Framework 6?

Comment: Follow this post for more clarity:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232633/entity-framework-timeouts

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Check this :

**Entity Framework 6 :**

```
this.context.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
```

**Entity Framework 5:**

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this.context).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;
```

**Entity Framework 4 and below:**

```
this.context.CommandTimeout = 180;
```

Comment: Thanks.  That fixed many occurrences of this build error for me: Upgrading from Entity Framework 5 to EF6  Error BC30456 "'CommandTimeout' is not a member of"

Comment: For EF 6.2 at least this needs to be placed in Configuration class in the migrations folder in the constructor:  public Configuration(){ CommandTimeout = 3600; }