# How to set CommandTimeout for all 400 pages in asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
 DbCommand oDBCommand = oDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand("Proc_GetCourseWithStatus");
oDBCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

// we can not  set CommandTimeout  in all pages in existing application,
 we also set in connection string in web.config but it taking default 30 sec only

```
// oDBCommand.CommandTimeout = 100;

oDatabase.AddInParameter(oDBCommand, "InstitutionCode", DbType.Int32, iInstCode);

oDatabase.AddInParameter(oDBCommand, "UserApplicationLoginActivityID", DbType.Int64, loginActivityLogID);
```

Comment: This is the way you use at a first place some kind of DAL.... or now you start changing....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Timeouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232633/entity-framework-timeouts)