# asp.net application timing out

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, orm, .net-4.5

we have asp.net application which when calling the SQL View, is timing out and throwing this exception[image]

i have set the following values on httpruntime key:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="60000" maxRequestLength="409643"/>
```

but it still times out after exactly 30 seconds. the session timeout is set to 20 minutes. any clues what i am doing wrong please?

the view returns all the records within 4 seconds.

Comment: did you using lot of methods in page load?

Comment: no there are only 2 methods inside my page load.

Comment: The exception is from SQL not asp.net and you are setting timeout for asp.net execution

Comment: @Adil our DBA can't find any issues as he is saying the view is returning results within 4 seconds. he also run update db stats which previously according to him, fixed this timeout issue. also shouldn't asp.net still wait for the given timeout period before throwing the wait operation timed out error?

Comment: What time it takes if you execute that query, if it is some stored procedure then catch the call through SQL server profiler and execute that call in sql server to verify how much time it takes?

Comment: Also if you are using entity framework or other orm then try to find out time out setting there, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232633/entity-framework-timeouts

Comment: it takes 4 seconds. it's a sql view.

Comment: we are using LLBLGen Pro ORM

Comment: You need to set _command timeout_ on the database connection, not http runtime or session. It's default 30 seconds. If the execution in SQL Management Studio is fast but not from code, it sounds like a case of parameter sniffing.

Comment: did u tried with sqlcommand.CommandTimeout=0?

Comment: i did not touch the code as it's in our production server but will give it a try in our dev environment . what's parameter sniffing?

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/