# Pass parameter to class which inherits from DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

My application is an `ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API`. I am using `Entity framework`.

I wan't to change the `CommandTimeout` like this:

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
   private const int Timeout = 180;

   public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options)
   {
       this.Database.SetCommandTimeout(Timeout);
   }
}
```

this works if `Timeout` is defined in my class.

However, I would like to have the value of my `Timeout` inside my `appsettings.json` file like this:

```
  "DbContextSettings": {
    "Timeout": "180"
  }
```

so there are two ways to set the `CommandTimeout` now:

1. Pass the `CommandTimeOutInSeconds` as a parameter to the constructor.
2. Get the value out of `appsettings.json` inside the constructor of my class

I don't know how to achieve one of the ways.

Is this possible? or is there any known workaround?

**Edit**

Iam never really Initailizing `MyDbContext`. I do this in `ConfigureServices` in the `Startup` class like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(db => db.UseSqlServer("secret"));
```

**Edit 2**

@dennisanberlin so let's say I have a controller calling the following method:

```
public class SomeRepository
{

  private MyDbContext context;

  public SomeRepository(MyDbContext myContext)
  {
     this.context = myContext;
  }

  public Person SomeMethodCalledByController(){
     return myContext.SomeTableWhichContainsPersons.FirstOrDefault(person => person.name == "Bob");
  }
}
```

The class `SomeRepository` is never getting initialized by me. Iam doing this via `dependency injection` in the `startup` like this:

```
services.AddTransient<SomeRepository>();
```

The class knows about `MyDbContext` from the above shown line:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(db => db.UseSqlServer("secret"));
```

Therefore I never pass an object of `MyDbContext` directly to any of my classes working with the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the timeout to your constructor like this:

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options, int timeout): base(options)
   {
       Timeout = timeout;
       this.Database.SetCommandTimeout(Timeout);
   }
```

And here is an example on how to read settings from your App settings.json [csharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/setting-and-reading-values-from-app-settings-json-in-net-core/)

**EDIT**

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options)
   {
       int timeout = //return timeout setting from appsettings.json
       this.Database.SetCommandTimeout(Timeout);
   }
```

You can try to do it that way, that you read your appsettings.json inside your constructor.

Comment: But how do I pass the timeout to the constructor? Iam never initializing MyDbContext, see my edit

Comment: Maybe you can initiliaze it before you to your **AddDb** Method.

Comment: the constructor gets called at every request on my sql database so setting the value once might not work

Comment: Like ‘MyDbContext dbcontext = new MyDbContext(paramater);‘

Comment: As I said the constructor of the class gets called my the entityframework itself at every sql statement on the database. I can't call the constructor by my self. And even if I would, I would have to to this at every database call which would be like 3000 lines of code and iam not even sure if it would work then

Comment: Maybe you can add more code, so i can see how you are calling this?

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt but please not the 3000 Lines of Code ^^ just the Code around your edit

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt Sorry but I dont get how you can pass it to your constructor, but I editied my answer with another idea. If you dont know how to read the settings from you appsettings.json, follow this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/setting-and-reading-values-from-app-settings-json-in-net-core/

Comment: sadly the appsettings can only be red from an IConfigurationRoot object, which I also can't pass to the constructor and the IConfigurationRoot object can only be created inside the Startup class

Comment: Sorry then I dont know, but I tried my best. I hope someone can asnwer this for you here. I upvoted it so maybe someone sees this