# Default Command Timeout is being ignored

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Background:

Ran across a problem in our production system where Entity Framework queries are NOT timing out after 30 seconds. We are using SQL Server 2014.

At one point we **were** seeing timeouts (ie if I ran a sql profiler trace we would see it run for 30 seconds and then throw a timeout error). But recently those aren't getting generated and I am seeing a couple problematic queries running very long. I don't have a specific time or change when we stopped seeing them.

This is a database first context. Our Context.tt file has been modified to alter the CommandTimeout for two stored procedures to 120 seconds and for 6 others to 0 (infinite timeout).

```
public string FunctionTimeout(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace)
    {
        if (edmFunction.Name == "StoredProc1" || edmFunction.Name == "StoredProc2")
            return string.Format("((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 120;");
        else if (edmFunction.Name == "StoredProc3" || edmFunction.Name == "StoredProc4" )
            return string.Format("((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 0;");
        else
            return "";
    }
```

Our dbcontext is registered in Autofac as follows

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This is being run in a Windows Service, but the data layer is also shared with a web api project.

.NET Framework 4.5.2

Entity Framework 6.1.3

Autofac 4.6.1

So question time:

1) Is setting the CommandTimeout causing it to be set at a "global" level? (ie once our system happens to call one of the stored procs above then every EF call after that has no timeout or a 2 minute timeout)

2) Is there a hook (in the template or elsewhere) to set it back to 30 secs before a regular EF call (ie before a LINQ query on a regular entity), not just stored procs (ie adding a return value on the else statement above)?

3) Would adding the CommandTimeout to the constructor help?

```
public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base("name=<#=container.Name#>")
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 30;
<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))...
```

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232633/entity-framework-timeouts), you are using the EF 5 version of how to set the timeout.

Comment: Well, I checked my NuGet Packages and EF 6.1.3 is what is in the project. I created a totally new project and added an identical model and it generated the same context.cs. I then went into my new project and deleted the old code generation files and did new EF 6 DbContext Generators and it generated identical files. So I don't have a good answer for which version it's really using

Comment: This is an old post, but just a question, does the 120 timeout work? if it does, why not changing your code on the `return ""` to `return string.Format("((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 30;");`?