# C# Entity Framework timeout creating DataTable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

VS 2015
EF 6.0

I am trying to automate a horrendous job: create a multi-sheet excel workbook where each sheet is the result of a different query.  First, if there is an existing, automatic way of doing this without rolling my own solution please let me know.  Otherwise:

I build up the collection of per-sheet queries then for each query string I do the following:

```
    ...
    "query" passed in as string above
    ...

    DataTable dt;
    using (var db = new MyDbEntities()) {
        db.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;

        try {
            dt = db.DataTable(query);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Datatable creation failed: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    ...
    create spreadsheet-sheet
    ...
```

I have one query that causes the exception: `Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding`

I am pretty sure that I am getting the timeout way before the 180 second timeout expires.  Timing it with my watch suggests the `DataTables` call is ignoring the `CommandTimeout`.  It seems to be timing out after about 30 seconds.

**EDIT**

The query in question was requested.  It follows.  It was inherited.  It is ugly.  It is a slow pig.  It is querying from a remote, linked Oracle DB and a couple of "local" DBs.  When run from `SSMS` it takes a few minutes to complete, but it does complete.

```
    SELECT
           UPPER(LOCAL_CONSUMER_TABLE.machine) AS machine,
           UPPER(LOCAL_CONSUMER_TABLE.personId) AS personId,
           Persons.LastName AS lastName,
           Persons.FirstName AS firstName
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
               GROUP_USER_ACCOUNT.UAC_ITU__ID
        FROM
             ORACLE_LINKED_SERVER..CONSUMER_TABLE.GROUP_USER_ACCOUNT AS GROUP_USER_ACCOUNT
        WHERE GROUP_USER_ACCOUNT.UAC_ITU__ID IN
        (
            SELECT
                   GROUP_USERVIEW.ITU_ITU__ID
            FROM
                 LOCAL_CONSUMER_TABLE.dbo.LoginInfoFinal AS LOCAL_CONSUMER_TABLE
                 INNER JOIN ORACLE_LINKED_SERVER..CONSUMER_TABLE.ITG_USER AS GROUP_USERVIEW
                      ON UPPER(LOCAL_CONSUMER_TABLE.personId) = UPPER(GROUP_USERVIEW.ITU_personId)
        )
            AND GROUP_USER_ACCOUNT.UAC_DATE_REVOKED IS NULL
        GROUP BY
                 GROUP_USER_ACCOUNT.UAC_ITU__ID
        HAVING COUNT(GROUP_USER_ACCOUNT.UAC_ITU__ID) > 1
    ) AS USER_ACCOUNT
    INNER JOIN ORACLE_LINKED_SERVER..CONSUMER_TABLE.ITG_USER AS GROUP_USERVIEW
         ON USER_ACCOUNT.UAC_ITU__ID = GROUP_USERVIEW.ITU_ITU__ID
    INNER JOIN LOCAL_CONSUMER_TABLE.dbo.LoginInfoFinal AS LOCAL_CONSUMER_TABLE
         ON UPPER(LOCAL_CONSUMER_TABLE.personId) = UPPER(GROUP_USERVIEW.ITU_personId)
    INNER JOIN FACILITY.Personnel.Persons AS Persons
         ON UPPER(LOCAL_CONSUMER_TABLE.personId) = UPPER(Persons.personId);
```

Comment: Can you show the *query* that causes the exception!?

Comment: Where are you settings the CommandTimeout? [is this the same problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232633/entity-framework-timeouts)

Comment: Edited to add query.  Also, the timeout is set just after the `using` above.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace of the exception?  Are you sure you're getting a _command_ timeout?  Perhaps you are getting a _connection_ timeout in which case setting `CommandTimeout` would have no effect.

Comment: Chris: First business day of a new month... I'll get back to this asap.  thanks for the ideas

Comment: Chris, it was indeed the connection timeout.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentioned, it was the connection timeout.