# SQL Server Connection timeout issue with application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

We have an application built in .NET with SQL Server as database where we are doing INSERT operations using EF(Entity Framework) and GET Operations using ADO.NET.

We are facing an issue recently in app where sometimes we are unable to do INSERT operation with exception of Timeout. We are able to fetch the data from application but unable to insert any data.

To resolve this we need to restart the SQL Server instance every time. But after one or two days again same situation arises where we are unable to do INSERT operations

NOTE : In ConnectionString we have kept Connection TimeOut value= 180.

Please find the stack trace error :

```
    MIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.Exceptions.BusinessException:
    at MIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.Business.Authorization.AuthorizationManager.SaveAuthorization (MIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at MIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.Web.Controllers.UM.Authorization.AuthorizationController.SaveCalypsoLyteAuthorization (MIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
Inner exception System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException handled at MIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.Business.Authorization.AuthorizationManager.SaveAuthorization:
   at MIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.DataRepository.EFRepository.EFGenericRepository`1.Save (MIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.DataRepository, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.DataRepository, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\Agents\UM\UM-Portal-01\_work\9\s\MIRRA.UM.Authorization.Data\EFRepository\EFGenericRepository.csMIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.DataRepository, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 435)
   at MIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.DataRepository.EFRepository.Authorization.AuthorizationRepository.SaveAuthorization (MIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.DataRepository, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.DataRepository, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\Agents\UM\UM-Portal-01\_work\9\s\MIRRA.UM.Authorization.Data\EFRepository\Authorization\AuthorizationRepository.csMIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.DataRepository, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 180)
Inner exception System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException handled at MIRRA.CareManagement.UM.Authorization.DataRepository.EFRepository.EFGenericRepository`1.Save:
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute (EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
Inner exception System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException handled at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError (System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning (System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun (System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData (System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData (System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader (System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds (System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader (System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader (System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
Inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception handled at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError:
```

Please suggest if anyone faced the same issue.

Comment: The timeout value in the ConnectionString only applies to the initial connection to the server. It has nothing to do with subsequent interactions with the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232633/entity-framework-timeouts)

Comment: With the limited information provided it really tough to assess, but if restarting the SQL server instance (releasing memory) it sounds like an insert operation is using up unnecessarily large memory on the SQL server?
Please post your insert code.