# Entity Framework issue connecting to Azure SQL MI database using Azure AD password authentication

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, azure-active-directory, adal

I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 web app that is using EF6.2 (Entity Framework) on 2012R2 server, connecting to an on-prem SQL server without any issues. Now, I am trying to connect the same app to an Azure SQL MI database from an Azure VM (2019 server) and I get ADAL-related errors. A console application with an Azure AD Password connection string works fine on the same machine. Also, the EF app works fine on the 2012 server,  it is the EF version app on the 2019 Azure server VMs that is having the issues. Any pointers in resolving this is really appreciated.

This is the connection string:

> <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityFramework.XXX.csdl|res://*/EntityFramework.XXXX.ssdl|res://*/EntityFramework.XXX.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=XXXX.XXXX.database.windows.net;initial catalog=testDB;persist security info=True;user id=me@mycompany.com;password=XXXX;authentication="Active Directory Password";MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

This is the error:

> InnerException: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
> AdalException: The request has timed out. at ADALNativeWrapper.ADALGetAccessToken
>
> ...
>
> in
> XXXXX\source\repos\SampleEF\DataObjects\EntityFramework\XXXX.cs:line 19

Comment: _AdalException: The request has timed out._ Seems like outbound HTTPS traffic (tcp/443) is blocked to the AzureAD/Office365 authentication servers such as login.microsoftonline.com. Are you able to use System.Net trace logs, or tools such as Fiddler, to confirm?

Comment: Thanks for your response Aaron ! Seems like outbound HTTPS is not the issue as a simple console app using the Azure AD password authentication can connect to the same Azure SQL MI database without any issues. Also, I did not see issues with tcp/443 in the fiddler trace. I was not able to get the System.Net trace logs work though. I suspect it is something to do with the EF and the ADAL version the server that is causing this issue. I am investigating further and will post if any progress.

Answer (score 0):

This error **AdalException: The request has timed out. at ADALNativeWrapper.ADALGetAccessToken"** usually occurs, if access to azure ad is blocked by your firewall or expiration of access token.

**To resolve this,**

- Try to add additional URLs or IP ranges to firewall.
- Try using token cache to make sure ADAL.Net refreshes if needed.
- Try increasing the connection timeout in the web.config while creating the database.
- Try adding the stored procedure

```cs
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ARITHABORT ON;
```

- If you are using Entity Framework define Time out on Startup class as below:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), o => o.CommandTimeout(180)));
```

- Try using the below syntax to change the timeout from the **default 30 seconds to 90 seconds:**

```cs
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
{
this.Database.SetCommandTimeout(90); // <-- 90 seconds
}}
```

**References :**

[c# - Entity Framework Timeouts - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232633/entity-framework-timeouts) by N-ate.

[Timeout and ADALGetAccessToken Error with AAD connections - Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/timeout-and-adalgetaccesstoken-error-with-aad-connections/ba-p/368806).

[Access token expired Issue · Issue #1596 · AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet · GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/1596).